# domain with my local page

Tags: virtualbox

I just configured my apache2 web service on my Linux distro (Linux mint), I added its own domain and an IP in my /etc/hosts/ file, from my virtual machine I can access my page through the IP that I created and the domain, but if I want to access from another device or computer it only supports the IP and accesses, while if I use my domain the page does not load

I am using the same network as my router, could you please help me?

Comment: I recommend looking up DNS. DNS is, basically, what translates between URLs and IP addresses.

Comment: hosts file is local only, if you're accessing from a different computer, you'd need to add the name and IP to that hosts file too, or implement some kind of DNS server to manage